# Session.refresh() in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have a question concerning section 4.6 of Hibernate specification located in
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userGuide/en-US/html_single/#d5e423

It is written in that spec:

> Note that only the entity instance and its collections are refreshed
>   unless you specify REFRESH as a cascade style of any associations

What does mean "its collections" in that statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means *its associations*.

Example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyEntity")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable
{
  //..
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="MY_ENTITY_ID")
    private Set<MyEntityFriend> itsFriends;
  //..
}
```

when **session** invokes **refresh()** on the entity instance `MyEntity` then this refresh also cascades to **itsFriends**.

Most commonly **refresh()** cascades to associations not explicitly defined but rather implicitly via **CascadeType.ALL**

Comment: Yes. I also thought about this but I am concerned with "unless you specify REFRESH". I.e. if you do not specify REFRESH then "instance and its collections are refreshed" and if you additionally specify REFRESH then associationas are refreshed too. Maybe there are some subtle things here?